Str is working without import facade in laravel 8
I am using str class in my helpers like below without import facade it is working fine without throwing any error. I am feeling little strange how it is working can any one explain.
if(!function_exists('testHelper')){
    function testHelper($string){
        $numbers = Str::replace(['(',')','-',' '],'',$string);
        return $numbers;
    }
}

if no need to import facade explicitly for str class ,how come it is working in which file it is bootstraped.Thanks in advnace !!

Laravel's Facade and some classes are registered as an alias.
It can be used without importing only in the global scope.
Blade view, config file, custom helpers, etc.
// blade
{{ Str::replace() }}

// controller
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
Str::replace();

// or (not recommended)
\Str::replace();

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php

but in aliases array they haven't mention helpers
Schema:"Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema"
Session:"Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session"
Storage:"Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage"
Str:"Illuminate\Support\Str"
URL:"Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL"
Validator
View
GlobalService
Excel
Xero
Flare
GoogleTranslate
Socialite
JWTAuth
JWTFactory
